# How to create custom fields in any module using REST API in SugarCRM?

Tags: php, api, rest, sugarcrm

How to create custom fields in any module using REST API in SugarCRM?
I am using sugar community edition 6.5.17.
Using REST api version 4.

Comment: This doesn't need to be put on hold, IMO, but it does need to be rephrased. The question is "Using SugarCRM, can I create custom fields using any of the available APIs?" and the answer is "No."